# getting server error 500 on drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); line

Tags: php, drupal

I got a zip file where drupal website was already installed . I am trying to run it in my local host So I copied all the files and put it under wwwroot\mysite folder.

I updated settings.php , db name etc. Now when I go to localhost\mywebsite , it gives error:

```
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

So I tried to debug and I printed line numbers by using echo just to see which line is giving me error and found that below line is giving this server error:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

I am not sure what wrong I did. Also It is not recording anything in php log file, in php.ini i have described my log location as:

```
 error_log=C:\Windows\temp\PHP71ForIISExpress_errors.log
```

here is my index.php file:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Comment: You may have to dig into `drupal_bootstrap()` to get a better understanding of this, but it is most likely due to a database issue and/or `settings.php` misconfiguration. Check that your db is up and running, and that you can actually query it using the drupal config from `settings.php`. Also there are a lot of contrib modules that are not PHP 7 compatible, so first you might want to check your PHP version.

Comment: earlier this drupal app was running on linux(apache) , now I am moving to windows, is it because of that ?

Comment: Theorically it shouldn't make any difference, but yes it _could be indirectly_ because of that (incompatible hard code and/or settings in drupal, or incompatible config in Windows/IIS). Compare the PHP versions and the databases on these servers.

Comment: checked for log file and it is empty, I reinstalled a fresh drupal and that is working fine but when I change databse back to the old db which I have all the contents , its shows 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked on other server then (most likely) problem is not in code but in your server settings. Try finding some log files (php, apache) and see what errors are recorded. May be that you don't have some required php library installed/enabled or something similar.

Comment: Create a file with just phpinfo() function call: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php 
Call it and look for log path or something like that..

Comment: checked for log file and it is empty, I reinstalled a fresh drupal and that is working fine but when I change database back to the old db which I have all the contents , its shows 500 error.

Comment: Empty error log means it's disabled. Try enabling it. Use the same phpinfo to find out where php.ini (php config file) is and edit it. Path should be displayed at top of phpinfo output. Edit it, find where error displaying is turnened off and turn it on. I can also enable php to print errors on screen if that's disabled.